# network connection problem after installing arch linux

Tags: wifi, archlinux

After installing Arch on acer c720 I rebooted and failed to connect to the internet with wifi-menu, getting these results instead.

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
lspci -k|tail -4
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:38:96:7b:4b:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
dmesg|grep firmware
[    5.276751] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
ip link set wlp1s0 up
ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:38:96:7b:4b:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
dmesg|grep firmware
[    5.276751] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
dmesg|grep firmware
[    5.623139] ath9k 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
dmesg|grep wlp1s0
[  241.764977] wlp1s0: authenticate with ac:a3:1e:e4:a1:92
[  241.775194] wlp1s0: send auth to ac:a3:1e:e4:a1:92 (try 1/3)
[  241.776256] wlp1s0: authenticated
[  241.777644] wlp1s0: associate with ac:a3:1e:e4:a1:92 (try 1/3)
[  241.778999] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from ac:a3:1e:e4:a1:92 (capab=0x1 status=0 aid=4)
[  241.779160] wlp1s0: associated
[  241.779745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[  241.813454] audit: type=1130 audit(1576018783.420:29): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=netctl@wlp1s0\x2dCity\x20of\x20Eugene\x2dFree\x20Public\x20WiFi comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  241.818154] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from ac:a3:1e:e4:a1:92 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  242.032750] audit: type=1131 audit(1576018783.640:30): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=netctl@wlp1s0\x2dCity\x20of\x20Eugene\x2dFree\x20Public\x20WiFi comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
```

If I have interpreted these results and the 'Wireless configuration' wiki correctly, what I need to do now is manually install the ath9k driver firmware from wherever it was stored on my system when pacstrap installed linux-firmware.

```
find / -iname '*ath9k*.xz'
/proc/irq/16/ath9k
/sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath9k
/sys/class/leds/ath9k-phy0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/leds/ath9k-phy0
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ath9k
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/ath9k
/sys/module/ath9k_common
/sys/module/ath9k_common/holders/ath9k
/sys/module/ath9k
/sys/module/ath9k/drivers/platform:ath9k
/sys/module/ath9k/drivers/pci:ath9k
/sys/module/ath/holders/ath9k_common
/sys/module/ath/holders/ath9k
/sys/module/ath/holders/ath9k_hw
/sys/module/mac80211/holders/ath9k
/sys/module/mac80211/holders/ath9k_hw
/sys/module/ath9k_hw
/sys/module/ath9k_hw/holders/ath9k_common
/sys/module/ath9k_hw/holders/ath9k
/sys/module/cfg80211/holders/ath9k_common
/sys/module/cfg80211/holders/ath9k
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko.xz
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko.xz
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_pci_owl_loader.ko.xz
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko.xz
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko.xz
/usr/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc
/usr/share/licenses/linux-firmware/LICENCE.open-ath9k-htc-firmware
/run/udev/tags/seat/+leds:ath9k-phy0
/run/udev/data/+leds:ath9k-phy0
find: paths must precede expression: `2'
```

The wiki has an early section titled 'installing firmware' but nowhere explicitly states how that should be done, and pacman seems to care only for .tar.xz.

```
pacman -U /usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko.xz
loading packages...
error: could not open file /usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko.xz: Unrecognized archive format
error: '/usr/lib/modules/5.4.2-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko.xz': cannot open package file
```

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lack of dhcpcd, and my aversion to using systemd.

I needed to download the package from Arch, install it and both enable and start it with systemctl, so that it persists after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar?? problem with the installation using a netgear wifi dongle:
(lsusb) NetGear, Inc. WNA1100 Wireless-N 150 [Atheros AR9271]

Wifi worked fine on the iso during the installation thanks to article by:
https://linuxcommand.blogspot.com/2013/10 for getting the wi-fi to work.

but was non-existent when booted up on the installed system.

On the installed system, dmesg | grep ath:

[   11.960144] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested

[   11.966726] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc

[   12.308917] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[   12.559791] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits

[   12.790286] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4

[   12.790290] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0: FW RMW support: On

[   12.790292] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60

[   12.790294] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map

[   12.790297] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00

[   12.790298] ath: Regpair used: 0x60

[   12.835277] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0 wlp0s2f1u3: renamed from wlan0

Tried using wlp0s2f1u3 to no avail:
(iw dev) displayed wlp0s2f1u3
but "device not found" etc when other commands used to set up the link using wlp0s2f1u3

Spent days hunting around trying to find a way to prevent wlan0 being renamed to wlp0s2f1u3 and eventually discovered that the installation iso had an extra file:

/lib/systemd/network/80-iwd.link

`[Match]`
`Type=wlan`

`[Link]`
`NamePolicy=keep kernel`

This file prevented wlp0s2f1u3 being renamed from wlan0 and I was able to get the network going using wlan0 instead of wlp0s2f1u3.

My thanks to all who were instrumental in finding my solution.